# cannot find symbol for call to service class

Tags: java, variables, find

I'm calling me fahrenheit2Celsius method in order to perform the expression, but it's saying my variable cannot be found. I can't seem to find my error. My service class will compile but my only error is the compiler cannot find the variable "celTemp". Here's my driver:

```
    /**
*   TempDriver.java
*   @author Sam Harrison
*   @version 9/17/2014
*/

import java.util.Scanner;
 public class TempDriver
 {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        TempConverter conTemp = new TempConverter();



        double initialTemp, faTemp;

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("MENU");
        System.out.println("0. Quit");
        System.out.println("1. Convert from Fahrenheit to Celsius");
        System.out.println("2. Convert from Celsius to Fahrenheit");
        System.out.println("Which option do you wish to perform?: ");

        int action = scan.nextInt();
        while (action == 1)

        {
            System.out.print("Intitial temperature: ");
                initialTemp = scan.nextDouble();


                conTemp.celsius2Fahrenheit(celTemp, initialTemp);

                System.out.print("The converted temperature is: " + conTemp + " degrees Celsius.");

        }

        action = scan.nextInt();
        while (action == 2)
        {
            System.out.print("Intitial temperature: ");
                initialTemp = scan.nextDouble();


                System.out.print("The converted temperature is: " + conTemp);
        }

        action = scan.nextInt();
        while (action > 2)
        {
            System.out.print("Error: invalid output");
        }


    }

 }
```

Here's my service class :

```
/**
*   TempConverter.java
*   @author Sam Harrison
*   @version 9/17/2014
*/
 public class TempConverter
 {
    public double celsius2Fahrenheit(double celTemp, double initialTemp)
    {

        celTemp = (initialTemp - 32) * 5/9;
        return celTemp;
    }

    public double fahrenheit2Celsius(double faTemp, double initialTemp)
    {
        faTemp = initialTemp * 9/5 + 32;
        return faTemp;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because `celTemp` is not defined and thus can not be found. First you must declare it:

```
double celTemp = <<some value>>;
conTemp.celsius2Fahrenheit(celTemp, initialTemp);
```

But in method `celsius2Fahrenheit` from `TempConverter` you define `double celTemp` parameter which value is not used in the function. It's strange. **Note that in Java there's no out parameter like in C#**. I think what you really want to do is:

```
public double celsius2Fahrenheit(double initialTemp) {
    double celTemp = (initialTemp - 32) * 5/9;
    return celTemp;
}
```

And in `TempDriver` you can call the method as:

```
    initialTemp = scan.nextDouble();
    double celTemp = conTemp.celsius2Fahrenheit(initialTemp);
```

Furthermore, when printing the result you are using `conTemp` that is an instance of `TempConverter`. That will result in something like TempDriver@35c41b, surely you want to use `celTemp` instead.